# mysqli_connect_error "Could not connect to mysqli:php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known"

Tags: php, mysqli

I'm new to php and mysqli and trying to connect to database but I got this error

> "Could not connect to mysqli:php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known"

stick in ubuntu and use xampp
this my code

```
<?php
define('DB_HOST', 'localhost');
define('DB_USER', 'root');
define('DB_NAME', 'first_db');
$dbc = mysqli_connect(DB_HOST,DB_USER,DB_NAME) OR die('Could not connect to mysqli:');
?>
```

Comment: ... localhost does not resolve to 127.0.0.1... You might add it in manually, but fix the server. If you used any other host then 'localhost', and this was just as an example, check your DNS resolving on your server. And of course, it's 'network address, user, PASS, database name', but that doesn't seem the source of the current error (but you will run into it once you fix the first one).

Comment: @user3659034 I think the OP hasn't replace the password with * but he simply removed the line.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, your missing the password and since the error was php_network_getaddresses try to replace localhost with 127.0.0.1

```
    <?php
    define('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1');
    define('DB_USER', 'root');
    define('DB_PASS', '');
    define('DB_NAME', 'first_db');
    $dbc = mysqli_connect(DB_HOST,DB_USER, DB_PASS, DB_NAME) OR die('Could not connect to mysqli:');
    ?>
```

If you want to use secured connection you can use PDO:

```
$pdo= new PDO("mysql:host=127.0.0.1;dbname=first_db", 'root', 'password');
```

**What mean php_network_getaddresses ?**

> It means PHP is trying to detect a hostname/address of a REMOTE PC
> (eg. a user browsing your page) but it cannot resolve the address
> (usually means that your server cannot query a DNS server or perform a
> lookup.)
>
> If this is annoying you, you can surpess the error message by adding a
> '@' at the start of the method... like so..
>
> by ballen

Comment: Could not connect to mysqli:php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known

Comment: try to restart mysql server

Comment: do you have any firewall installed ?

Comment: still not work ,no iam use kubuntu, when open localhost in browse is work i can access to mysql

Comment: I suspect it's a firewall issue try to flush all rules by running this command "sudo iptables -F"

Comment: i did that, nothing change

Comment: this output of iptables -L.
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Comment: I tried the code and it's working fine check your xampp logs for any error